# IllegalStateException: Activity does not have a NavController set on

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I try to write an Android app which uses the Navigation Component from androidx, a toolbar and a drawer layout to slide in a setting menu from the left. I followed the guides [Get started with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) and tried to add a top app bar and a setting using this guide [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui).

When my apps starts, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity ....MainActivity@e686cd8 does not have a NavController set on 2131230993
```

*Side remark:* If I open `nav_graph.xml` in design mode, the hosts pane reports *"No NavHostFragments found. This nav graph must be referenced from a NavHostFragment in a layout in order to be accessible."* Maybe this error and the exception are related and share the same root cause. However, my navigation graph is referenced by a `NavHostFragment` though, see below.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This layout

- contains a `FragmentContainerView`
- references `@navigation/nav_graph` (pasted below)
- contains a `NavigationView`
- references `@layout/nav_header` (pasted below)
- references `@menu/drawer_view` (pasted below)

**nav_header.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="192dp"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:padding="16dp"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

**drawer_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_home"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
      android:title="@string/home"/>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
      android:title="@string/settings" />
  </group>
</menu>
```

**fragment_home.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".HomeFragment"/>
```

This fragment is referenced by `nav_graph` (pasted below) as the home fragment (start destination).

**nav_graph.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
  app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="de.mhnnet.lychee4android.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
</navigation>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
  setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

  NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
  AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
    new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
  Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.main_toolbar );
  NavigationUI.setupWithNavController( toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration );
}
```

**Further Remarks:**

I already found some tips which says that `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` should be replaced by `fragment`. However, this feels wrong as the linter recommends to use `FragmentContainerView` instead of `fragment` and the [official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment) use `FragmentContainerView`, too.

Answer (score 13):

*Okay to get `Nav Controller` in your activity either replace your*

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

*with*

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

But as the lint suggest to change fragment with `FragmentContainerView` Use the below code to get `Nav Controller` in your activity.

```
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        if (navHostFragment != null) {

            NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

            // Setup NavigationUI here

        }
```

Comment: But this basically means that the original Google Android Docs are wrong. Also, the post which is linked above says that `findFragmentById()` must be used, because `findNavController` does not work in `onCreate()`. But the latter is what the Google Android Docs recommend.

Comment: It's a bug look at this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973